# Save OLE object from Clipboard

Tags: c#, .net, mfc, clipboard

I have unmanaged OLE object in clipboard.
I put it in clipboard via next code:

```
[DllImport("mfc80u.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.ThisCall, EntryPoint = "#1532")]
public static extern void COleClientItem_CopyToClipboard(IntPtr thisClientItem, int bIncludeLink);
```

How can I to learn whose it is object (for example Word, Excel or the image) and how to save it in the file via C#?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you do it in C#. I do know that you need to try and get the CF_OBJECTDISCRIPTOR clipboard format and inspect the resulting OBJECTDESCRIPTOR object's clsid member.  From the CLSID, you can see if it matches Word, Excel, etc.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683735(v=vs.85).aspx